# Call webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, axis

What is the procedure to call axis webservice(already running on my machine) through android application without using Ksoap2.

I want to implement the web service call using the HttpClient calls provided by default in apache http library. What is the procedure to pass the web method names.

Regards.

Comment: I think you want to make a webservice call and fetch a result, is it the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case you should implement simple Java client (outside of Android) to call your service hosted in Axis and use Fiddler or other HTTP proxy to capture exact request you need to call on Axis service and exact response you will get. Base on these two XMLs you can build your request from in android and also build logic to extract data from response. Without existing request and response you can go and study WSDL, XSD, SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 and also some other specifications if your Axis service uses security (but in such case even kSoap2 will not help you). Without that knowledge you can hardly build correct request from scratch.

There is no reason to avoid kSoap2. Doing it without kSoap2 will make your code only more error prone and more complicated.